# Morris.js how to create graph for specific type

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, morris.js

I have some troubles with create graph using **Morris.js** library. I created sport app and every training has some values. One of them is **"workout"** it means type of workout(**"Running","Swimming","Cycling"**). I want to display line graph with date and distance, but for specific type of training, for example **"Running"**. I created general graph with all dates and distances, but when I try to make graph for specific type it doesn't display proper one, but graph with sum of all running distances for every day(horizontal line). I don't know how to fix line in workouts_helper.rb *distance: Workout.where(workout: "Running").sum(:distance)*

***workouts_helper.rb :***

```
def running_chart_data
    (3.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
        {
            date: date,
            distance: Workout.where(workout: "Running").sum(:distance)
        }
    end
end
```

***application.html.erb :***

```
<script>
        new Morris.Line({
          element: 'running_chart',
          resize: true,
          data: $('#running_chart').data('running'),
          xkey: 'date',
          ykeys: ['distance'],
          labels: ['Distance']
        });
</script>
```

***index.html.erb :***

```
<h1>Last 3 weeks running graph</h1>

        <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "running_chart", data: {running: running_chart_data} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `distance` a column in your `Workout` table, or is it a method in your `Workout` model?

If it's a column:

```
Workout
  .where(workout: 'Running')
  .sum(:distance)
```

should work fine.

If it's a method, you'll need to do something like:

```
Workout
  .where(workout: 'Running')
  .to_a
  .sum(&:distance)
```

Or

```
Workout
  .where(workout: 'Running')
  .sum{ |w| w.distance }
```

It's also worth noting that the query is going to return the same result set for every date in your range. If this is what you really want, it probably makes sense to move the query outside the iteration like this:

```
def running_chart_data
  distance = Workout
               .where(workout: 'Running')
               .sum{ |w| w.distance }

  ((Date.current - 3.weeks)..Date.current).map do |date|
    { date: date,
      distance: distance }
  end
end
```

Looking back over your question, I suspect that your issue might be that you're not taking `date` into account in your `distance` calculation.

You may want to add a check for the `date` like:

```
def running_chart_data
  ((Date.current - 3.weeks)..Date.current).map do |date|
    distance = Workout
                 .where(workout: 'Running',
                        created_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day)
                 .sum(:distance) }

    {  date: date,
       distance: distance }
  end
end
```

Comment: "distance" is my column. I changed helper code, but all time I get horizontal line - every day have sum of "Running" distance.

Comment: See the last example I added... think that may be your issue.

Comment: You rock dinjas ;) I must changed "created_at" to "date", because when I add some training with date from the past it all time add distance to actual date, but it was was not the problem. Thank you for help :)